# Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView2'. Remove one definition

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to reload a gridview upon date selected from calendar.

*I know there are duplicate questions on SO but their answers did not work for me*

```
 protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
        DataSet ds = dlObj.FillDataSet("SELECT top 5  [DName], [bloodGroup], [dateDonated] FROM [tblDonors] ORDER BY [dateDonated] DESC ", "tblDonors");
        GridView2.DataSource = ds;

        GridView2.DataBind();

        }
```

And the method FillDataSet() is this

```
public DataSet FillDataSet(string q, string tableName)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(q, thisConnection);
        da.Fill(ds, tableName);
        return ds;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return ds;
    }
}
```

When I click any date, this error occurs

```
Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView2'.  Remove one definition.
```

Comment: `but their answers did not work for me` why?

Comment: show your gridview markup.. make sure you are not setting DataSourceID property of your gridview on aspx page.

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli
http://codepad.org/Xly3u4Yj

Comment: Romve this from your code DataSourceID="ds" and try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 DataSourceID="ds"
```

This is not needed when you are adding datasource from code behind.

Answer (score 5):

While, in general, you should really decide on whether to use design side datasource or use code behind, there may be occasions where it is preferable to use both.  One way to cheat a bit, in code behind use:

```
grid.DataSourceID = null;
grid.DataSource = dataTable;
grid.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Calendar1_SelectionChanged` you should simply call

> GridView2.DataBind()

and handle whatever it is you are trying to do in the

> DataSourceID_Selecting

event by updating e.Result

Comment: It shows the error 
Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView2'. Remove one definition
on line:  GridView2.Databind()